# need to display particular data from database by clicking on the particular button or a link reg

Tags: javascript, html, express, pug

I am creating a question forum as my project. I am displaying the questions frm a table in a databse but iam not getting the idea how to display the answers to that particular question when I click some button which refers to that question...

I have made question as a url link and I want to search for that exact words in that link in a databse but it is navigating to that link instead of searching for those words contained in a link in a database. How can I be able to open a new page which displays the question as well as various answers(which are stored in a database) to that particular question by clicking on that question link by searching the link in a databse instead of searching it in routes. 
I want as in stack overflow website or any other logic.
i have written the code using pug.

```
h1=title                                                                          
-for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ )                                               
  -var url=String(data[i]["title"])                                                    
  p #{String(i+1)}.                                                                
  p: p Title: #[a(href="/"+url) #{url}]                                  
  p Question: #{String(data[i]["question"])}                                 
  p Asked By: #{String(data[i]["username"])}                         

a(href="/post")
  button(type="button") Ask a question
```

display the question as well as its related answers from a database in a new page by clicking on that question as a link. But it is searching for that link in routes and says error 404 not found

Comment: Hi @Shaik, can you take another attempt at formatting the pug code? The indentation is hard to understand currently.

Comment: If "But it is searching for that link in routes and says error 404 not found" then we will need to see your routing code in order to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I have not yet written the routing code. I need you to give me some idea of how to retrive data from database from that link or that type of button. Like in stack overflow if we click on the question a separate page will appear which contains question, answers and replies or comments. Ineed that type of functionality in my website. How can I do it?